# I wish to restore a gzipped tarball - what does mongodump --archive do? Howto do a mongorestore with --gzip?

Tags: backup, mongodb, restore, compression, mongodb-3.2

I created a backup with

```
mongodump -h $RANDOM_SECONDARY_SUP -u $BACKUP_USER -p $BACKUP_PASSWD --out /data/$BACKUP_USER/sup-repl/sup_$DUMPFILE
tar cvzf /data/$BACKUP_USER/dbt/st_$DUMPFILE.tar.gz /data/$BACKUP_USER/st-repl/st_$DUMPFILE
```

I tried to restore that with `--gzip` and receive erorr

```
mv st_$DUMPFILE.tar.gz test_restore.bson.gz
mongorestore --gzip test_restore.bson.gz
2016-09-08T18:05:14.975+0200    checking for collection data in tgdmead2_test_restore.bson.gz
2016-09-08T18:05:15.090+0200    restoring test.test_restore from tgdmead2_test_restore.bson.gz
2016-09-08T18:05:15.156+0200    Failed: test.test_restore: error restoring from test_restore.bson.gz: reading bson input: invalid BSONSize: 1635017060 bytes
```

In docs I read that the gzipped tarball should be created with `--archive`

What does this parameter do? Howto emulate that with `tar` and `gz`?

Which format does mongorestore expect with `--gzip`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem you have is that the archive format created with `--archive` is not a tarball (and the docs don't say it is anywhere that I could find). Rather it is a custom packaging format which you can see the details of [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/blob/v3.2/common/archive/archive.go). Based on a quick scan of the code, it looks like a lightweight format containing a series of headers, metadata which describes the raw BSON. Short of creating a standalone binary to create a compatible archive file, you can't do this manually.

If you do `mongodump` without archive, but with `--gzip`, it will actually [gzip the individual files](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption--gzip), and you can emulate that by doing the dump normally then gzipping each file in the folder separately. Those compressed files could then be restored theoretically with `mongorestore --gzip`.

Overall I would advise to just use `--archive` in the 3.2 tools and stay away from trying to recreate it manually, but the `--gzip` option is as close as it is going to get without a bunch of work.